# D3 zoom, drag do not work on Angular2 Material Design

Tags: angular, d3.js, material-design

D3 zoom, drag do not work on Angular2 Material Design. Zoom, drag events are not triggered.

```
 d3.drag()
  .on('start', () => {
    console.log('drag start');
    //his.setClickOrigin(d3.event);
  })
  .on('drag', (d, i, n) => {
    console.log('drag');
  });
```

There is a related issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/SgguQRsDSXU
But it does not give a solution for.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have to attach the drag object to an svg object.
`this.svg.call(drag)`